# Search Results Showing Wrong Excerpt

Tags: simple-search

I have a simple search form that seems to be displaying incorrect excerpts. In the channel I am searching, I have 2 channel fields, a file field and a description field.

I have the radio button for the file field set to not be included in search results and I have the radio button for the description field set to be included in search results.

When I try a search for a word that I know to be in the description field, the results gives me the URL of the image in the file field.

Any thoughts as to why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe so. My understanding is that the radio field is for "should this field be searchable", not "should this be the excerpt on the results page". To set this, go to Admin > Channel Administration > Channels > YOUR CHANNEL > Edit Preferences > Administrative Preferences > Which field should be used for search excerpt? > Use the select box to pick the correct field.

It does seem a bit back to front, but makes sense when you have much more complex channels.

Comment: Thank you! I totally forgot about that channel setting. That was the ticket!

Comment: Cool, no problem :)